# How to fetch ArrayMap and String data from Firebase to Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I need to fetch Array/Map data from Firebase cloud to flutter.

I have sent data to Firebase and want to make Order History by fetching customer order Data from Firebase. I don't know to how fetch Data, because it is Map data which is in an Array. I have attached picture of my Firebase data and what i want explained in picture.

I have tried QuerySnapShot but getting only 1 product data like this `['Products']['0']['Cart Name']`

Comment: Can you share your code that you've tried (as text and not image)?

Comment: Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)